# Detecting TextInput changes on an editable ComboBox in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, textinput

If my ComboBox is editable how can I tell if a change event comes from a change to the TextInput or a change in the selectedIndex of the drop down?

Is there a way to check for this in the event object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `selectedIndex` property on the ComboBox--if your change happened in the dropdown list, this will be an index in the list; otherwise it will be -1.

See [ComboBox.selectedIndex](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#selectedIndex).

Comment: Lets say the user has already made a dropdown change and then edits the textfield. I can hold a reference to the previous selectedIndex for comparison but if I can pull this info from the event, I'd rather do that.

Comment: You're right. When you edit the text, the selectedIndex is set to -1. Thanks.